# Write to a csv file scrapy

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I want to write to csv file in scrapy

```
 for rss in rsslinks:
  item = AppleItem()
  item['reference_link'] = response.url
  base_url = get_base_url(response)
  item['rss_link'] = urljoin_rfc(base_url,rss)
  #item['rss_link'] = rss
  items.append(item)
  #items.append("\n")
 f = open(filename,'a+')    #filename is apple.com.csv
 for item in items:
    f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

My output is this:

```
{'reference_link': 'http://www.apple.com/'
 'rss_link': 'http://www.apple.com/rss '
{'reference_link': 'http://www.apple.com/rss/'
 'rss_link':   'http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wpa/MRSS/newreleases/limit=10/rss.xml'}
{'reference_link': 'http://www.apple.com/rss/'
 'rss_link':  'http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wpa/MRSS/newreleases/limit=25/rss.xml'}
```

What I want is this format:

```
reference_link               rss_link  
http://www.apple.com/     http://www.apple.com/rss/
```

Comment: Look at the csv modult in the standard library

Comment: I found this class scrapy.contrib.exporter.CsvItemExporter(file, include_headers_line=True, join_multivalued=', ', **kwargs)
But i don't know how to use this with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

1. Write your header row; then
2. Write the entry rows for each object.

You could approach it like:

```
fields = ["reference_link", "rss_link"] # define fields to use
with open(filename,'a+') as f: # handle the source file
    f.write("{}\n".format('\t'.join(str(field) 
                              for field in fields))) # write header 
    for item in items:
        f.write("{}\n".format('\t'.join(str(item[field]) 
                              for field in fields))) # write items
```

Note that `"{}\n".format(s)` gives the same result as `"%s\n" % s`.

Comment: Be more specific. What have you tried to do to understand it; have you tried testing parts of it in a Python interpreter?

Comment: It actually doesn't work when I tried it. Is this the complete procedure to write it? You haven't closed format and f.write's brackets.

Comment: I get an error saying: f.write("{}\n".format('\t'.join(str(field) for field in fields))) # write header
exceptions.ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Then you are probably using Python 2.6 or earlier. Try `"{0}\n".format(...)`.

Comment: Yes this is working. But it repeatedly adds the headers. So in between links there are headers as well

Comment: Then move the header write outside whatever loops you have!

Comment: I removed the header write. So it works perfectly. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 105):

simply crawl with `-o csv`, like:

```
scrapy crawl <spider name> -o file.csv -t csv
```

Comment: I am creating a file for each domain. This will create just one file for all the domains.

Comment: By modifying your `pipelines.py` file. You don't need any of the above code and can control the output formatting, order and when to export. I did something similar [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753358/how-can-i-use-the-fields-to-export-attribute-in-baseitemexporter-to-order-my-scr). Defining my own `spider_opened(...)` function.

Comment: In the newer scrapy versions it seems to be: `scrapy runspider <spider name> -o file.csv -t csv`

Comment: was wondering if suppose in such a case, if we have 2 different parse functions and we want to write 2 separate files for each of them, can it be done?

Comment: can you explain what is -t  parameter

Comment: `-t` specifies the [format](https://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) for dumping items.

Comment: can you please explain the differnece between -o and -O?

Comment: -O overwrites the file if it exists but -o appends to it.

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me using Python3:

```
scrapy runspider spidername.py -o file.csv -t csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Best approach to solve this problem is to use python in-build **csv** package.

```
import csv

file_name = open('Output_file.csv', 'w') #Output_file.csv is name of output file

fieldnames = ['reference_link', 'rss_link'] #adding header to file
writer = csv.DictWriter(file_name, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
for rss in rsslinks:
    base_url = get_base_url(response)
    writer.writerow({'reference_link': response.url, 'rss_link': urljoin_rfc(base_url, rss)}) #writing data into file.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI' : 'Quotes.csv'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [tablib](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/).

```
dataset = tablib.Dataset()
dataset.headers = ["reference_link", "rss_link"]

def add_item(item):    
   dataset.append([item.get(field) for fields in dataset.headers])

for item in items:
    add_item(item)

f.write(dataset.csv)
```

---