# How to maintain Item's Field Names in one file with Scrapy?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

In scrapy, it involves a lot of Item's field names writing.

**1. Item class (Items.py)**

```
class HelloItem(scrapy.Item):
   Name = scrapy.Field()
   Address = scrapy.Field()
   ...
```

**2. Spider class (spider.py)**

```
class HelloSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def parse(self, response):
       item = HelloItem()
       item["Name"] = ...
       item["Address'] = ...
       ...
```

**3. settings.py**

```
EXPORT_FIELDS = ["Name", "Address", ...]
```

I defined `EXPORT_FIELDS` setting in `settings.py` to be used for defining the fields ordering for custom CSV item pipelines. The CSV pipeline code is like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20758558/844005), except the `self.exporter.fields_to_export` is loaded by `settings.getlist("EXPORT_FIELDS")`.

You can see there are three places I have to define the field names (Name, Address, etc). If one day I have to rename some field names, I have to change them in those three files.

So is there a way to unite the Item's field name definitions in just one file? (or two files is also alright, the lesser is better than nothing)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* not use items at all, and yield dictionaries instead. That way, you would not need `items.py` at all.

However, as a project grows, defining an `Item` subclass is recommended, and the repetition you mention is a *lesser evil*.

Thanks to defining an Item you can get an error message when you try to scrape an item field with a typo in one of your spiders.

Item classes also allow you to work with [item loaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html).