# CSV Exports - Ordering of columns using scrapy crawl -o output.csv

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there a way to specify the order of the columns in a CSV output using the -o parameter?

It seems to follow a random order and does not follow the order in the items.py file or when the item fields get populated in the scrape.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a relevant [`field_to_export` attribute](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.BaseItemExporter.fields_to_export) in [`CsvItemExporter`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#scrapy.contrib.exporter.CsvItemExporter), but, as far as I understand, there is no way to set it from the command-line. You need to do it through the pipeline, see:

- [How can I use the fields_to_export attribute in BaseItemExporter to order my Scrapy CSV data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753358/how-can-i-use-the-fields-to-export-attribute-in-baseitemexporter-to-order-my-scr)

Answer (score 8):

You can solve it from adding a line in settings.py

```
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
```

Comment: tried adding it. Didn't work for me.