# Scrapy. Results in wrong sequence

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I write scrapy script, and I almost finish. I have one problem. Results don't collect in the right sequence. Please look on my problem, this is code:

```
import scrapy


class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "molo_spider"
start_urls = ['https://example.com']

def parse(self, response):

    for result in response.xpath('//body'):
         yield {
             'test1': result.xpath('//div[@class="eoDetailNewBrand"]/span[1]/text()').extract_first(),
             'test2': result.xpath('//div[@class="eoDetailNewBrand"]/span[2]/text()').extract_first(),
             'test3': result.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"][1]/@content').extract_first(),
             'test4': result.xpath('//tr[@class="erDetailItem erFontSizeS"][2]/td/span[1]/text()').extract_first(),
             'test5': result.xpath('//tr[@class="ekDetailItem ekFontSizeS"][2]/td/span[3]/text()').extract_first(),
             'test6': result.xpath('//tr[@class="elDetailItem elFontSizeS"][2]/td/span[5]/text()').extract_first(),
             }
```

I get my result (csv file) in perfect but in wrong sequence:

test2...
test3...
test5...
test6...
test1...
test4...

I need:
test1...
test2...
test3..
etc

How do this correctly?

Comment: You should use appending elements (test1,test2...) to lists and create a DF from lists. It will be in sequence as you described in DF.

Comment: Ok, thanks for Your sugestion.

Comment: You need to set an order for output headers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368912/csv-exports-ordering-of-columns-using-scrapy-crawl-o-output-csv

Comment: @gangabass, Thanks for Your help. Super

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py simply add

FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ['text1',text2','text3']