# How to print Scrapy item keys in the correct order?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have Scrapy Item, for example:

```
class QuotetutorialItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    country = scrapy.Field() 
    state = scrapy.Field()
```

When I yield this Item, i get fields in alphabetical order.

How I can keep the fields order the same as in class structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41301998/67579

Comment: where do you want to keep it in correct order ? on screen ? in csv file ?

Comment: [CSV Exports - Ordering of columns using scrapy crawl -o output.csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28368912/csv-exports-ordering-of-columns-using-scrapy-crawl-o-output-csv)

Comment: see also [FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-fields) in settings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get order of fields in Scrapy item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41293916/how-to-get-order-of-fields-in-scrapy-item)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I saw that, I'm new to Python and Scrapy and don't understand    that solution

Comment: @furas in json file

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the following attribute [custom_settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html)

```
class YourSpiderClass(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_name'
    start_urls = ['http://blahblah.com/']

    custom_settings = {
            'FEED_URI': 'file.csv',
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
            'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': [
                'Url',
                'Country',
                'State',
             ],
         }

    def parse(self, response):
    # you actions
```