# Scraping site and creating .csv file with Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to run a spider which grabs certain pieces of information from http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&eventid=0&gameid=2 and creates a .csv file with the data. I'd like the spider to go through each date and scrape key pieces of information for each listed date: http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=19029&eventid=0&gameid=2

This is what I have so far:

```
import scrapy

class hltvspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hltvspider"
    allowed_domains = ["hltv.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&eventid=0&gameid=2"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

Here is the output I get:

```
C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\HLTV\HLTV\HLTV\spiders\hltv.py:5: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: HLTV.spiders.hltv.MySpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inhe
rit from scrapy.spider.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: HLTV)
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'HLTV.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['HLTV.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'HLTV'}
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaR
efreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [hltvspider] INFO: Spider opened
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [hltvspider] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-01-21 16:20:22-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-01-21 16:20:23-0600 [hltvspider] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&eventid=0&gameid=2> (referer: None)
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n        ', u'\n        ', u'\n      ']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t']
[] [] [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t']
2015-01-21 16:20:23-0600 [hltvspider] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-01-21 16:20:23-0600 [hltvspider] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 241,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 13544,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 22, 20, 23, 432000),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 21, 22, 20, 22, 775000)}
2015-01-21 16:20:23-0600 [hltvspider] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719263/write-to-a-csv-file-scrapy

Answer (score 0):

check if this works for you

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from megacritics.items import MegacriticsItem

class testspider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pupu"
    allowed_domains = ["hltv.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&eventid=0&gameid=2"]

    def parse(self,response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@style="width:606px;height:22px;background-color:white"]')
        items = []
        for site in sites:
            item = MegacriticsItem()
            item['date'] = site.select('.//div[@style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px;"]/a/div/text()').extract()
            # item['team1'] = site.select('.//div[@class="covSmallHeadline"]/text()').extract()
            # item['team2'] = site.select('.//div[@class="covSmallHeadline"]/text()').extract()
            # item['map'] = site.select('.//div[@class="covSmallHeadline"]/text()').extract()
            # item['event'] = site.select('.//div[@class="covSmallHeadline"]/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```